# what would be initial capacity of a new dynamodb ondemand table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

If I create a new on-demand dynamodb table, what would be its initial allocated read and write units?

This link shows 40k read and write units - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html#default-limits-throughput-capacity-modes

Provisioned tables converted to on-demand will have provisioned units set as allocated ondemand capacity - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html

Comment: With on-demand, there are no allocated read/write units.  40k that you mention is the max throughput that can be achieved by default. In tables that are set to on-demand, you pay per number of requests that are made, so the question of allocated read/write units doesn't make sense for on-demand tables

Comment: right, what I meant to ask was how much is the max peak set for new on-demand tables which haven't been used at all?

Answer (score 0):

A newly created on-demand mode table has a previous peak of 2000 WCU and 6000 RCU.

As you can consume double your previous peak that allows you to make 4000 WCU and 12000 RCU per second.

Comment: Where does this information come from? The DynamoDB documentation (linked by OP) and Service Quota page in AWS accounts show read and write throughput limits for on-demand tables to be 40000

Comment: The OP is not asking about quotas, they are asking about initial allocated read and write units. The table level soft limit is 40k which is a different thing altogether.

Comment: what does table level soft limit mean? does it mean the max peak a table can go is 40k? I think that's not the case as I have seen tables with higher peaks.

Comment: That's why its called a soft limit, you can increase beyond that limit with a request using Service Quotas. But without a limit increase in place you will be throttled beyond 40k.